# Dispose dynamic created Controls (Labels) in a quick way

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have a lot of dynamic created Labels in a Windows Form, nearly 30 x 80 pieces.

The disposing of this controls works very slow. It takes nearly 1 second where I can see it work step to step.

I use the following code (to dispose all the controls, where the Name starts with "var":

```
For i As Integer = dlg_main.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
 If LCase(Left(dlg_main.Controls(i).Name, 3)) = "var" 
    dlg_main.Controls(i).Dispose()
 End If
Next
```

Is the a quicklier way to dispose the controls?

Comment: Not really.  Try calling `dlg_main.SuspendLayout` before the loop and `dlg_main.ResumeLayout` afterwards to see if it helps.  2,400 labels isn't very useful to the user — surely they don't need to see all that at once on the screen.  Consider a DataGridView instead otherwise.

Comment: I have already tried. To slow, SuspendLayout is not a solution to make it work faster.

Comment: Don't ignore the second part of my comment.  Just drawing your matrix would be your other solution.  Over 1,000 controls is an extremely taxing design.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put the labels in a panel then Dispose the panel.

```
Panel1.Dispose()
```

Comment: OK, I will try using a Panel.

The 2400 Labels dont show text but colors, borders etc., so that a colored matrix is shown. Thats why i need so many small labels.
In former applications i developed with VB6.0 it works realy fast with the same code!

Comment: @mischarichter - That's a common misconception when migrating from VB6 to VB.net.  Even though they are similar languages, migrating means re-thinking your approach a lot of the time.

Comment: ok, but if I want to add Labels to a (disposed) panel, what is the code?

First I have to create a new panel as a new dynamic object and then I have to add the labels in this panel.

Comment: @mischarichter - You should probably create a custom panel class that inherits from the existing panel class and have the default constructor fill it with labels. This will make adding new panels much simpler.

Comment: OK. That was easy: creating a panel and add all my labels.
But if when i dispose the panel and in the next step i want to create it new, then it is not visible/not existing.
What is the problem re-Creating a disposed panel at runtime?

Comment: Did you create a custom class for it? Are you adding the new panel to the controls collection of the form?

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved, see how to declare and to initialize:

Module mdl_main
    Private pn1 As System.Windows.Forms.Panel

```
Public Sub ShowPanelAgain()
    pn1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Panel
    pn1.Name = "dynPanel1"
    dlg_Main.Controls.Add(pn1)
    pn1.AutoSize = True
    pn1.AutoScroll = True
End Sub

Sub PanelLöschen()
    Try
        If pn1.IsDisposed = False Then
            pn1.Dispose()
            dlg_Main.Text = "pn gelöscht"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Fehler: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```